# Nested Joins in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

How do I do nested joins in SQLAlchemy?  The statement I'm trying to run is

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, c.col3 
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (b INNER JOIN c ON c.col4 = b.col4) ON b.col5 = a.col5
```

I need to show all records in `A`, but join them only with those records in `B` that can `JOIN` with `C`.

The code I have so far is

```
session.query(a.col1, a.col2, c.col3).outerjoin(b, b.col5 == a.col5).all()
```

This gets me most of what I need, with `A` records showing null values where it's missing `B` records; however, too many `B`s are getting in, and I need to limit them.  However, if I just add another join, i.e.,

```
session.query(a.col1, a.col2, c.col3).outerjoin(b, b.col5 == a.col5).join(c, b.col4 == c.col4).all()
```

It drops out all of the `A` records with null values in `B`.

I should point out that I can't join `A` to `C` directly because the only connection between the two is through `B`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done easiest using [`subquery`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.subquery):

```
subq = (session.query(b.col5).join(c, c.col4 == b.col4)).subquery("subq")
qry = session.query(a).outerjoin(subq, a.col5 == subq.c.col5)
print(qry)
```

If you showed more of the model definition and especially the nature of the relationships between the tables, there might be a more elegant solution.